# Connecting 4 digital MEMS microphones with raspberry pi 4

Tags: audio, rpi.gpio, microphone, robotics

I want to add 4 INMP441 digital MEMS microphones to the GPIO pins of Raspberry pi 4 to perform sound source localisation.

Here's a reference link to the mic: https://robu.in/product/inmp441-mems-high-precision-omnidirectional-microphone-module-i2s/?gclid=CjwKCAiAioifBhAXEiwApzCztoUeo5VuBrtSFQYbl6_9TnM_MW8JvmZ6-p_USflxKZf5BR87sbBx8hoCw7gQAvD_BwE

Questions in particular:

1. The mics have a pin named WS. What does it do & where to connect that?
2. I have to record 4 individual audios. So, should I connect all the SDAs together or connect them seperately? Same question for SCLs
3. The mics also have L/R selectors, Should I make them L & R according to the placement or can I keep them all in one mode?

Comment: They use I2S which is NOT compatible with I2C.

Comment: This might help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/140455/how-can-rpi-pico-w-control-a-gpio-pin-connected-i2c-digital-mems-microphone/140465#140465

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, but you may find some of the information helpful in your research:

There are [at least 264 Q&As here re I2S](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=I2S). Start with that, and narrow the list. For example, here are two:  [1](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/79870/confirming-the-i2s-pins-on-raspberry-pi-3-model-b), [2](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47799/i%c2%b2s-pins-on-raspberry-pi-3).

Wrt the RPi4 hardware in particular, see the [BCM2711 ARM Peripherals documentation; Chap 7](https://datasheets.raspberrypi.com/bcm2711/bcm2711-peripherals.pdf). Please do a bit of research first, and then edit your question.